# Tin can Api implementation in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, tin-can-api

I have developed LMS system using mvc. Now i want to implement the tincan api to store and retrieve the courses.

I referred the https://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCan.NET/ url but dont know how to begin. Do we need separate location to store the course if so then how to store and retrieve.

In above mentioned url sample code, there is a service call "https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/public/" but dont understand what is it and how to get it.

Guys please help to start with it. I gone through several url but not getting it.

Comment: I have got the meaning of https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/public/ url and also gave username password. but getting error as "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are confusing project tin (now known as xAPI) can with SCORM.

SCORM does everything with an LMS, and requires you always stay online.

However, project tin can doesn't store courses, only statements. This allows you to run your coursework without internet, and then submit the statements once you do have a secure connection again.

You may want to check out the [xAPI Spec](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec) before continuing and see if this is what you want to use (I highly recommend it, as SCORM is becoming a bit outdated)

If you do want to continue working with xAPI, there are lots of sources on the [ADL GitHub](https://github.com/adlnet?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=) page.

---

Now in order to somewhat better answer your question: If you do want the course to be online, you need it on another page and use a [wrapper](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPIWrapper) to send the information to the LRS (not an LMS).

Hopefully this helps! :-)

---

### Additional resources

[ADL's public LRS](https://lrs.adlnet.gov/)

- This LRS can only hold a few statements, but it's a good way to test if your code works, and practice using xAPI

[ADL's GitHub Page](http://adlnet.github.io/)

- This is a list of information and additional sources.
- Includes a section explaining how to go from SCORM to xAPI (which is what it looks like you're trying to do)

[Vocabulary list for xAPI statements](http://xapi.vocab.pub/)

- List of Verbs, Activity Types, Context Extensions, Result Extensions, & Attachment USAGE Types
- Useful for forming well structured and fully conformant statements

[Tin Can Article](https://experienceapi.com/tin-can-experience-api-xapi/)

- Brief article explaining in normal language what xAPI really is
- Includes additional sources of information, should you wish to do more research